# Laravel route url changing after app()->handle() function

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I'm accessing an api in my own project, but now I'm having problem with the `route` function, after dispatching the request with `app()->handle($req)`, route function generate a different url

```
   $req = Request::create('/api/auth/login', 'POST', [
        "user" => $request->user,
        "password" => $request->password,
    ]);

    $redirect = route('home'); // http://127.0.0.1:8000/home

    $res = app()->handle($req);

    $redirect = route('home'); // http://localhost/home
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Is the code for a test? Curious why you're calling `app()->handle()` directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Request::create()` is a method inherited from Symfony's HTTP Request class. When called, if you do not pass in any `$_SERVER` details, [it will use reasonable defaults](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/7e7b3c05ff74dff2f049dc71e74b7f0c7ee1daf6/Request.php#L311-L324).

The `UrlGenerator` Laravel class uses the current Request to determine the fully-qualified domain name when calling functions such as `route()`. Since you did not tell the Request what the current domain is, it is reverting to `localhost`.

If you're in an environment where `$_SERVER` is populated with the proper information, you can pass it to the proper parameter:

```
Request::create(
    '/api/auth/login',
    'POST',
    [
        'user' => $request->user,
        'password' => $request->password,
    ],
    [], // cookies
    [], // files
    $_SERVER
);
```

Other potential solutions that may fit well:

- Use `Request::createFromGlobals()` to populate a request with PHP's superglobals such as `$_POST`, `$_SERVER`, etc., then modify the parts that you want to change.
- If the `$request` variable already holds a Laravel Request instance, you can call `$request->duplicate()`. And again, modify as needed.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you